# Debugger Opens While Compiling Inline Assembly Code

Tags: c++, inline, inline-assembly

I am using some code from Github, but it won't compile. The debugger opens in the middle of the code compiling. This is a personal project and it would be really helpful if anyone could make useful edits to the code as I am new to assembly.

Here is the output that I am getting until the debugger opens:

> 'Assembly.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Users\Mayank\Desktop\Assembly\Debug\Assembly.exe', Symbols loaded.
>   'Assembly.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or
>   open the PDB file 'Assembly.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Assembly.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file 'Assembly.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded. First-chance
>   exception at 0x011013fe in Assembly.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
>   Unhandled exception at 0x011013fe in Assembly.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack
>   overflow.

Here is the code:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  MergeSortC
//
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Mayank. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
const int ARRAYSIZE = 30;

int main()
{
    int arr[ARRAYSIZE];
    int temp_arr[ARRAYSIZE];
    int number;

    for(int x = 0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x++)
    {
        number = (rand() % 99) + 1;
        arr[x] = number;
    }

Merge_Sort:
    __asm
    {
        // EAX - Array start
        // ECX - array length

        // Merge_Sort (first half)
        // Length of the first half
        // ECX /= 2
        push  ECX
        shr   ECX, 2
        call  Merge_Sort
        pop   ECX

        // Merge_Sort (second half)
        push  arr
        push  EBX
        push  ECX

        // Length of the second half
        // ECX = ECX - ECX/2
        mov   EDX, ECX
        shr   EDX, 1
        sub   ARRAYSIZE, EDX
        imul  EDX, 4
        // Start index of the second half
        // EAX = EAX + (ECX/2) * 4
        add   arr, EDX
        push  EDX
        call  Merge_Sort
        pop   EDX

        pop   ECX
        pop   EBX
        pop   arr

        pushad
        // Merge (first half, second half)
        // Length of first half = ECX/2
        // Length of second half = ECX - ECX/2
        mov   EDX, ECX
        shr   ECX, 1
        sub   EDX, ECX

        // Start of second half = EAX + (ECX/2) * 4
        mov   EBX, EAX
        mov   EDI, ECX
        imul  EDI, 4
        add   EBX, EDI
        // Index of temp array = 0
        sub   EDI, EDI
        call  Merge
        popad

        // Copy back the merged array from temp_arr to arr
        call  Merge_Copy_Back_Temp

        ret
    };
Merge:
    __asm
        {
        // Merge two arrays contents.
        // The final merged array will be in temp_arr
        // Merging is done recursively.

        // Arguments:
        // EAX - First array's start
        // EBX - Second array's start
        // ECX - Length of first array
        // EDX - Length of second array
        // EDI - Index in temp array
        pushad

        // Handle the cases where one array is empty
        cmp   ARRAYSIZE, 0
        jz    First_Array_Over
        cmp   EDX, 0
        jz    Second_Array_Over

        // Compare first elements of both the arrays
        push  ARRAYSIZE
        push  EDI
        mov   ECX, [arr]
        mov   EDI, [ECX]
        cmp   ECX, EDI
        pop   EDI
        pop   ECX

        // Pick which ever is the least and update that array
        jl    Update_First_Array
        jmp   Update_Second_Array
        ret
    };

Update_First_Array:
   __asm
   {
        // min_elem = min (first elements of first array and second array)
        // Put min_elem into the temp array
        push  dword ptr [EAX]
        pop   dword ptr [temp_arr + EDI * 4]
        add   EAX, 4
        dec   ECX
        inc   EDI

        // Recursively call Merge on the updated array and the
        // other array
        call  Merge
        popad
        ret
   };

Update_Second_Array:
   __asm
   {
       // min_elem = min (first elements of first array and second array)
        // Put min_elem into the temp array
        push  dword ptr [EBX]
        pop   dword ptr [temp_arr + EDI * 4]
        add   EBX, 4
        dec   EDX
        inc   EDI

        // Recursively call Merge on the updated array and the
        // other array
        call  Merge
        popad
        ret
   };

Merge_Copy_Back_Temp:
   __asm
   {
        // Copy back the temp array into original array
        // Arguments:
        // EAX - original array address
        // ECX - original array length
        pushad

        // For copying back, the destination array is EAX
        mov   EBX, EAX
        // Now, the source array is temp_arr
        mov   EAX, temp_arr
        call  Copy_Array
        popad
        ret
   };


First_Array_Over:
   __asm
   {
        // Copy the rest of the second array to the temp arr
        // because the first array is empty
        pushad
        mov   EAX, EBX
        mov   ECX, EDX
        mov   EBX, temp_arr
        imul  EDI, 4
        add   EBX, EDI
        call  Copy_Array
        popad
        popad
        ret
   };

Second_Array_Over:
   __asm
   {
    // Copy the rest of the first array to the temp arr
    // because the second array is empty
    pushad
    mov   EBX, temp_arr
    imul  EDI, 4
    add   EBX, EDI
    call  Copy_Array
    popad
    popad
    ret
   }; 
Copy_Array:
   __asm
   {
    // Copy array to destination array
    // EAX - Array start
    // EBX - Destination array
    // ECX - Array length

    // Trivial case
    cmp   ECX, 0
    jz    Copy_Empty_Array

    push  ECX
    sub   EDI, EDI
   };
copy_loop:
   __asm
   {
    // Copy each element
    push  dword ptr [EAX + EDI * 4]
    pop   dword ptr [EBX + EDI * 4]
    inc   EDI
    loop  copy_loop

    pop   ECX
    ret
   };

Copy_Empty_Array:
   __asm
   {
    ret
   };

Read_Arr:
   __asm
   {
        // EAX - array start
        // ECX - array length
        mov   ESI, arr
        sub   EDI, EDI
   };
loop1:
   __asm
   {
        // Read each element
        lea eax,[esi+edx*4]
        inc   EDI
        loop  loop1
        ret
   };

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dare to disbelieve about the debugger opening during *compilation*. That said, this code

```
Merge_Sort:
    __asm
    {
        // EAX - Array start
        // ECX - array length

        // Merge_Sort (first half)
        // Length of the first half
        // ECX /= 2
        push  ECX
        shr   ECX, 2
        call  Merge_Sort
```

*has* to overflow the stack when running: pushing ECX, shifting ECX, calling itself.

Comment: It's a recursive merge-sort. Although that does look a bit dubious, I have to say. The value in ecx is unlikely to be "ARRAYSIZE" - it may have been in the original compiler this was compiled with, but surely something needs to load ECX with ARRAYSIZE and then check if ECX is zero at some point.

Comment: @MatsPetersson `LABEL: (some instructions but no branches); CALL LABEL` has to be *infinite* recursion, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think so too - I said that it needs to check ECX for zero at some point.

Comment: So how should I fix this? I think I know what you are saying.

Comment: @Mayankmmmx sorry, the whole exercize is not interesting enough to me to dig out "what did you mean by this code". It's not the first thing to fix, obviously: more important is *why do you think* that EAX is array start, and ECX array length. It seems very wrong.

Comment: I have no clue. I got this code from Github and tried embedding it. Here was the code: https://github.com/hugopeixoto/mergesort/blob/master/assembly/mergesort.asm

Comment: Why don't you implement a merge-sort in C first, and understand how it works. Then try to write it in Assembler. I expect the compiler actually does a better job as well.

Answer (score 0):

Short of installing the compiler myself, I suggest that you work through the code by adding `#if 0 / #endif` around a bunch of the code and seeing if you can figure out which instruction(s) the compiler is upset about - it clearly is the compiler crashing, which isn't a very good thing, but does happen.

Of course, that's after you have googled for the error message, etc... ;)

Comment: I guess I will try to see. Do you by any chance know which line of code I can fix?

Comment: No, since that would require me to a) start my second machine and fix the broken network  connection on it (I know what to fix, but it's a bit of a mess), then fire up the windows virtual machine, then install Visual Studio, and doing what I describe above to find which one. I don't get more than at most 25 points for this answer, and that's at least half an hours work - at nearly midnight, that's not a good "points for effort..." ;)

Comment: Alright i'll give oyu the 25 points (that is if I learn how to) and we can also come to an agreement on paypal if needed.

Comment: The point is that you are the one who want's to learn how to program. I already know how to solve this type of problem [to the degree it can be solved - it's entirely possible that your code can't be fixed in a way that is suitable for Visual Studio and still does what it should].

Comment: Sorry, I misread your message. The error is in your code - it is blowing the stack, as Anton has said. He deserves the 25 points for pointing out the error. For some reason, I thought it was Visual Studio's compiler that was crashing.

Comment: Click the "Tick" box for "correct answer" and "up-arrow" for "Like this answer". You may have to earn some credit or wait some time before you do that.

Comment: Darn. I need more points. Can you please tell me. I will be forever grateful. I could also donate money! please please please

Comment: How to fix it.. Not sure, but the problem is that your code is forever recursing into Merge_Sort... You need fix it so that ECX is initialized to ARRAY_SIZE, and then check in each call to Merge_Sort whether it is finished or not.

Comment: So how would you approach this problem